# Overlaying a line graph and an area graph: adding recession bars to a time series

Tags: time-series

I am trying to reconstruct a time series graphs from FRED: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/LABSHPUSA156NRUG using Python. However, I am unable to get a clean figure where the time series is overlaid with the area graph representing the recession bars.

I am quite new to python so it's been frustrating to find a simple reason why my attempts are not working.

I have attempted this two ways.

My first attempt looks like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ls_data.plot.line(ax=ax, figsize=(8,5), x='Date', color=blue)
rec_data.plot.area(ax=ax, figsize=(8,5), x='Date', alpha=0.5, color=gray)
plt.ylim(0.59,0.65)
```

And produces the following perplexing mess: [image]

My second attempt goes for the "ax2 = ax1.twinx()" route

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ls_data.plot.line(figsize=(8,5), x='Date', color=blue)
rec_data.plot.area(figsize=(8,5), x='Date', alpha=0.5, color=gray)
```

However this produces two separate figures instead.

[image]

[image]

One possible issue is that the x-values for the labor share are plotted in individual years whereas the x-values for recession are plotted in months. But based on the second attempt, it looks like the graphs should overlay smoothly but then I'm liable to get the same result as in my first attempt. Would transforming the recession data provide a fix?

Edit: The data for recession dates are available here. [https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/USREC#:~:text=For%20daily%20data%2C%20the%20recession,the%20month%20of%20the%20trough](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/USREC#:%7E:text=For%20daily%20data%2C%20the%20recession,the%20month%20of%20the%20trough).

Comment: Can you share the input data for the recession periods?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The recession data are given in binary terms where months in recession are given a value of 1 and a value of 0 otherwise.

You can download the data set here: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/USREC#:~:text=For%20daily%20data%2C%20the%20recession,the%20month%20of%20the%20trough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data from FRED for both [labour data](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/LABSHPUSA156NRUG) and [recession data](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/USREC) and slight adjustments to your code I think I get the result you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read in data
rec_data = pd.read_csv("USREC.csv")
ls_data = pd.read_csv("LABSHPUSA156NRUG.csv")

# make sure date columns are actual dates
rec_data["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(rec_data["DATE"])
ls_data["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(ls_data["DATE"])

# create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ls_data.plot.line(ax=ax, figsize=(8, 5), x='DATE', color="blue")
rec_data.plot.area(ax=ax, figsize=(8, 5), x='DATE', alpha=0.5, color="gray")
plt.xlim("1950-01-01", "2020-01-01")
plt.ylim(0.58, 0.65)
```

[image]

Comment: By god, you're a hero. Thank you.

Comment: I hate to be the jerk to tell you that this doesn't work as well as it looks from far away. If you zoom, you'll see that your lines are not vertical: remake the plot between 2007 and 2010 exactly as before to see what I mean. Your problem is the same as the one in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47962876/pandas-dataframe-recession-highlighting-plot. I'm not honestly sure what causes the problem, something to do with mixing annual with monthly data. Maybe the algorithm picks the midpoint (July), which does not coincide with the start/end of the recession monthly units.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a problem with Oxbowerce's answer, so I'd like to provide an alternative. The recession data is monthly, while the labour market data is annual: To address this discrepancy, I resample the annual data to monthly, interpolating with a simple mean, merge the data, and plot. With the data merged on the same dates, odd visual artifacts disappear.

**1. The problem**

To see the problem with Oxbowerce's approach, let's create a plot for a smaller sample of data. Using Oxbowerce's code but zooming on 2007-2009:

**The recession lines are not vertical!**

[image]

**2. One solution**

There may be a `pandas` workaround to seamlessly plot data at different frequencies without the strange artifacts above, but I don't know it, so I take the long way round and resample the data.

**2a: resampling to monthly with forward filling '.ffill()'**

```
dy = df.set_index('DATE').resample('M').ffill().reset_index()
d1 = pd.merge(dr, dy, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=("", "_y")).drop(labels='DATE_y', axis=1)
```

**Intermediate Product:**

[image]

Now the labour market data looks jagged. So we interpolate.

**2b: resampling to monthly with '.mean().interpolate('linear')'**

```
# interpolate data | MS='Month Start', default is M=ME='Month End'
di = df.set_index('DATE').resample('1MS').mean().interpolate('linear').reset_index()
d2 = pd.merge(dr, di, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=("", "_y")).drop(labels='DATE_y', axis=1)
```

**Final Product:**

[image]

Code to plot recession areas:

```
# convenience function
def plot_series(ax, df, index, cols, area, **kwargs):
    # convert area variable to boolean
    df[area] = df[area].astype(int).astype(bool)
    # set up an index based on date
    df = df.set_index(keys=index, drop=False)
    # line plot
    df.plot(ax=ax, x=index, y=cols, **kwargs)
    # extract limits
    y1, y2 = ax.get_ylim()
    ax.fill_between(df[index].index, y1=y1, y2=y2, where=df[area], facecolor='grey', alpha=0.4)
    return ax

# plot resampled data with method='ffill'
f, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_series(ax, d1, index='DATE', cols='LABSHPUSA156NRUG', area='USREC')
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()

# plot resampled data with .mean().interpolate('linear')
f, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_series(ax, d2, index='DATE', cols='LABSHPUSA156NRUG', area='USREC')
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Questions regarding {MS='Month Start', default is M=ME='Month End'}. The problem is that if you don't have the start of the month, or the end of the month, either "MS" or "M" will miss the start or end of a month sometimes. For instance, the stock market does not open on 2022-12-31 because it's a Saturday, neither does it open on 2022-10-01 because it's a Saturday as well. In such cases, if you use "MS", you will combine Sep 2022 and Oct 2022 together because python does not see "2022-10-01" in the time series, and it continues to search from 2022-09-01 to 2022-11-01. Likewise, if yo